# What are the consequences if Webcam/Camera still being turned on

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc

I'm trying to develop a javascript based web application and I have to let the camera (whether built in camera or external webcam) be turned on. Are there any bad things will be happened in near future ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to ask the user for permission; that would be a serious security breach IMHO. Also, people might think that the NSA is spying on them and be mad and never come to your website again. However, I've found [This library](https://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/) for webcam stuff

Comment: Is there any affection to my hardware performance, if i use it be turned on. Will its lifetime be decreasingly down ?

Sorry for my bad question, but my curiosity is calling me.

Comment: Battery life may decrease, and the computer may be a bit slower, but not sure exactly what you're asking

Comment: yes that were what i was actually asking :)
thanks in advance :)